# How do i work with abstract and concrete models in .net tutorial?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-6) and after I set the `Person` entity as `abstract` in the model I get the following error:

> Type 'SchoolModel.Person' in conceptual side  cannot be mapped to
>   type 'ContosoUniversity2.DAL.Person' on the object side.  Both the
>   types must be abstract or both must be concrete types.

I thought that I needed to change the `Person.cs` and make it abstract.
After changing the file I run again and got:

> Could not find the CLR type for 'SchoolModel.Student'

I am using Visual Studio 2012. Any ideas how to fix this?

Contents of `Person.cs` :

```
namespace ContosoUniversity2.DAL{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.StudentGrades = new HashSet<StudentGrade>();
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> HireDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

    public virtual OfficeAssignment OfficeAssignment { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentGrade> StudentGrades { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
}
```

Piece of code in my Students.aspx where i get the error

```
 <asp:GridView ID="SearchGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PersonID"
    DataSourceID="SearchEntityDataSource" AllowPaging="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="LastName, FirstName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LastNameFoundLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>, 
                <asp:Label ID="FirstNameFoundLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enrollment Date" SortExpression="EnrollmentDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="EnrollmentDateFoundLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EnrollmentDate", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If you need more code just ask and I will update.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you need to is to update entity framework to latest version so that you can all the latest feature.

Another thing you need to understand is inheritance strategy in Entity Framework.

**Table per Hierarchy (TPH):** This approach suggests one table for entire class inheritance hierarchy. Table includes discriminator column which distinguish between inheritance classes. This is a default inheritance mapping strategy in Entity Framework.

**Table per Type (TPT):** This approach suggests seperate table for each domain class.

**Table per Concrete class (TPC):** This approach suggests one table for one concrete class, but not for the abstract class. So if you inherit the abstract class in multiple concrete classes then the properties of the abstract class will be part of each table of concrete class.

See link as bottom in that they have already used entity framework 6 with Abstract class.

```
 public abstract class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [Column("FirstName")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName;
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: i just found out i was using the wrong framework(the tutorial was for 4.0 and i was using 4.5 *cries*). Still your awnser is smooth. Thanks very much

Comment: i had to wait 6minutes, you are coding lucky luke